# error showing in my .ts code > [ts] Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

My coding working fine. data showing on page, but an error accruing in VSE editor

Like this

> [ts] Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

my .ts file code is here

```
ngOnInit() {
    const data = {
      tailor_id: this.edit_id,
      user: this.userToken
    };
    this.https.post<any>('api/tailor/details', data).subscribe(response => {
      this.tailor = response.tailor;
      this.editTailorForm.controls['name'].setValue(this.tailor.name);
      this.editTailorForm.controls['phone_number'].setValue(this.tailor.phone_number);
    });

  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show me the declaration of this.tailor?

Comment: You have declared `trailor : any[]`, which is an array, So you should be accessing it like `this.tailor[0].name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared `tailor: any[]`, which is an array, So you should be accessing it like `this.tailor[0].name`.

If `tailor` is an object, then declare it as `tailor: any`

And access like `this.tailor.name`.

**Note** : It is always good practice to use proper type like `class` , `interface` or typed object like `tailor : {name: string, phone_number: number}` to group object properties instead of using `any`

Comment: i have declared    'tailor: Array<any> = []'

Comment: Its the same as `tailor: any[]`. From your code what I understand that `tailor` is an object and not array, because you say your code is working fine. So just declare `tailor: any`. See answer for the detail.